# Port qmake *.pri source-library to CMake

Tags: qt, cmake, qmake

I have small frequently modified *.pri source-libraries, purpose of those pri's is to add headers and sources, do aux tasks like copy file. Those libraries are at same or higher directory level than the project that will use them and must have access to parent project variables (e.g ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR)

example of *.pri:

```
#AnFeature/AnFeature.pri
HEADERS += $$PWD/anfeature.h
SOURCES += $$PWD/anfeature.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
OTHER_FILES += $$PWD/android/src/example/anfeature/anfeature.java
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$QMAKE_COPY_DIR $$shell_path($$PWD/android/src/example/anfeature) $$shell_path($$ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR/src/example/anfeature)
```

Looking how to implement that kind of stuff via CMake 3.19 or newer

Comment: Hi, you probably miss my previous comment. So, in result it should be: library CMakeLists.txt without preamble (project(), etc.) with target_sources(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ...) and target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ...). That library should be included via Include() in root project's CMakeLists.txt, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `HEADERS` and `SOURCES` are just variables, so you can use [target_sources](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html). You can even set the source property on targets using [set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html).
2. For `INCLUDEPATH`, you can use [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html). Or simple specifying your library dependency after finding it with [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) using [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html)
3. For `OTHER_FILES`, you can just again [set a cmake variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) if you really need to.
4. For running custom commands, like `QMAKE_POST_LINK` does, you can use [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246655/discussion-on-answer-by-laszlo-papp-port-qmake-pri-source-library-to-cmake).